# Cold water and flour

Tags: flour, water

Does flour and water of 45 degrees Fahrenheit rise? I thought that it has to be warmer, or they wont react at all. 
Will it rise just at a slower paace?

Comment: Water and flour and yeast? Or just water and flour?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: it will still rise just slower. Every week when I make bread I make the dough the night before, put it in the fridge (which is about 40 degrees) and use it the next day. The dough usually doubles in size by the morning.

There is a nice breakdown of the temperate range of yeast at https://www.bobsredmill.com/blog/baking-101/what-temperature-kills-yeast/

Comment: You are right,  although your answer would be better if you put the temperature ranges in your answer and cited the link. The range data on that site actually has an error in it, saying that the range 68F to 104F will hinder the yeast, the author meant to write -4F, not 104F.